# ASP.NET Javascript Services Server Side Render Specific Routes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, server-side-rendering

With Microsoft's [ASP.NET Javascript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) is it possible to pick and choose which routes get rendered server side?

I need marketing pages like the home page to get rendered on the server for SEO, but the web app pages to only be rendered on the client.

I am using react, react router and asp net core 2.0.

Comment: If it's possible (I'd also like to know), it's probably also possible for Angular

Answer (score 0):

Use **asp-prerender-*** in a view, as described here

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#server-side-prerendering

For example, in your cshtml:

```
<div id="my-spa" asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/boot-server"
             asp-prerender-data="new {
                IsGoldUser = true,
                Cookies = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies
             }"></div>
```